# Codename One app not provide real location

Tags: geolocation, codenameone, android-gps

in out app we have a module where you can send time records with GPS location.

In 40% of cases we have location problem because the module provides a location which is not real (sometime about 1 km away).

When we have this cases we open Google Maps app and it give us perfect location, then again out app and not-real location.

For getting the location we use this:

```
Slider s1 = new Slider();
Dialog dlg = makeDialog("HIGH PRECISION LOCATION...", s1, null, 'a');
dlg.addShowListener((ActionListener) e -> {

    LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager.getLocationManager();                
    locationManager.setLocationListener(this, new LocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCUARCY, 500));

    loc = locationManager.getCurrentLocationSync(20000);

    dlg.dispose();
    if(loc == null) {
        Slider s2 = new Slider();
        Dialog dlg2 = makeDialog("GETTING LAST KNOWN LOCATION...", s2, "OK", 'a');
        dlg2.addShowListener((ActionListener) e2 -> {
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation();

            if(loc == null) {
                // location not found
                Dialog.show("Attenzione!", "Posizione non trovata. E' consigliato di spostarsi all'aperto. "
                        + "Tuttavia è possibile inviare la timbratura anche senza coordinate.", "Ok", null);
            } else {
                paintLocation(loc, GPSStateOn);
            }
        });
        dlg2.show();
    } else {
        paintLocation(loc, GPSStateOn);
    }

});
dlg.show();
```

-

```
@Override
public void locationUpdated(final Location location) {

    switch (LocationManager.getLocationManager().getStatus()) {
        case LocationManager.AVAILABLE:
            GPSStateOn = true;
            break;
        case LocationManager.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            GPSStateOn = false;
            break;                
        case LocationManager.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            GPSStateOn = false;                 
            break;                
    }

    if(loc != null) {
        paintLocation(loc,GPSStateOn);
        System.out.println("-----LATITUDINE: " + loc.getLatitude());
        System.out.println("-----LONGITUDINE: " + loc.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

We also have added the buil hint `android.playService.location = true`

---

**ADDED 25/04/2020 11:58**
I forgot to say that about 40% of cases it arrives at "GETTING LAST KNOWN LOCATION..." and then give perfect real location.
Android build hints:
[image]

---

last one is cutted... value is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"         android:required="true"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/><uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

---

**ADDED 06/05/2020 10:48**

Maybe this can be useful:
I noticed when the location takes a lot the GPS icon isn't displayed in the topbar
[image]

And when it takes less time the GPS icon is visible
[image]

Comment: This sounds exactly like the missing `android.playService.location` problem. Please check that the spelling is correct in codenameone_settings.properties. If it is please list all the android.* build hints you have.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I have edited original question adding Android build hints (see "ADDED 25/04/2020 11:58 part")

Comment: Did you look in `codenameone_settings.properties`? It's easier to see a mis-spelled entry there.

Comment: I don't know what I have to look for.
My `codenameone_settings.properties`: https://pastebin.com/raw/xQ04qgVQ

Answer (score 0):

Looking again at the code I noticed you used set location listener and `getCurrentLocationSync` which are mutually exclusive in this case. You need to pick one. If you give the former (which is the preferred way) enough time to work it should give you an accurate location. Notice the GPS position sometimes needs a couple of seconds for the initial reading.

Comment: I've tried setting the listener... Sometimes take more then 30 seconds, when still loading I close app, then I start it again and voilá: perfect position in 2 secs

Comment: But I can't say to costumers to restart app, Google Maps always take at most 2 second

Comment: Is this happening only on your device or other devices as well? Are you sure the listener callback was never invoked?

Comment: Yes, because in the callback I dispose a loading dialog... And it is never disposed

Comment: Or the callback is invoked so quickly that the dialog didn't have time to show fully yet

Comment: I've edited original question adding two screenshot which maybe are useful for you - See "ADDED 06/05/2020 10:48"

Comment: I think it's the exact opposite. I think you get the callback so fast the dialog isn't showing yet so you can't dispose it. Did you guard properly against that case?