# Codename One location sometimes not working

Tags: gps, location, codenameone

Old question: [Codename One app not provide real location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403935/codename-one-app-not-provide-real-location/61451083?noredirect=1#comment109049623_61451083)

We still have problem getting current location.

Sometimes it's ok, "Localizzazione..." dialog shows, then location ok callback dispose the dialog.

Sometimes the dialog is never disposed and I don't see GPS in the top bar, which is visible when location is ok and dispose the dialog.

```
Slider s1 = new Slider();

Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    blocco_loc_in_corso = makeDialog("Localizzazione...", s1, null, 'a');
    blocco_loc_in_corso.show();
});

LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager.getLocationManager();
locationManager.setLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
        if(location != null) {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                if(blocco_loc_in_corso != null) {
                    blocco_loc_in_corso.dispose();
                }
            });
            paintLocation(location, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void providerStateChanged(int newState) {

    }
}, new LocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCUARCY, 1000));
```

I have this problem for at least 6 months. We only need to block user until we have his GPS location which may can change (GPS updates callback).

**Edited:**

```
public Dialog makeDialog(String label, Component c, String buttonText, char btIcon) {
    Dialog dlg_r = new Dialog();
    Style dlgStyle = dlg_r.getDialogStyle();
    dlgStyle.setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
    dlgStyle.setBgTransparency(255);
    dlgStyle.setBgColor(0xffffff);

    Label title = dlg_r.getTitleComponent();

    title.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0xff);
    title.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.LEFT);

    dlg_r.setLayout(BoxLayout.y());

    Label blueLabel = new Label(label);
    blueLabel.setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
    blueLabel.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff);
    blueLabel.getStyle().setFgColor(0x0a0afc);
    blueLabel.getStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
    blueLabel.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    blueLabel.getUnselectedStyle().setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS);
    dlg_r.add(blueLabel);
    dlg_r.add(c);
    if (buttonText != null) {
        Button dismiss = new Button(buttonText);
        dismiss.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
        dismiss.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0);
        dismiss.getAllStyles().set3DText(true, true);
        dismiss.setIcon(FontImage.createMaterial(btIcon, dismiss.getStyle()));
        dismiss.addActionListener(((evt) -> {
            dlg_r.dispose();
        }));
        dlg_r.add(dismiss);
    }
    return dlg_r;
}
```

Comment: I need to see the code of `makeDialog` generally it shouldn't show at all if `locationUpdated` is invoked. It would also be interesting to log in `providerStateChanged` just to make sure everything is in order.

Comment: I have edited the answer with `makeDialog` code

Answer (score 0):

To make sure this code is threadsafe make the following change:

```
public void locationUpdated(Location location) {
    locationFound = true;
    // ...
}
```

Then in the make dialog method:

```
dlg_r.addShowListener(e -> {
     if(locationFound) {
         dlg_r.dispose();
     }
});
```

Since this event can happen in the dead time of showing the dialog transition.

Comment: Unfortunately we're trying to reproduce the issue you're experiencing without success so far